# Unexpected token u in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have an Ajax function that sends and retrieves a string. Once the Ajax receives the string, it calls a function called `drawChart`. `drawChart` then converts that string into an array using `JSON.parse` I am also using Google Charts to create a chart using the data that was passed in. Everything is working correctly. The chart is being made and it looks all fine, however; I am getting this error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at
>   position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at drawChart (index.js?c1496931740:24)
>       at anonymous

I did research this error and it happens when the data type that is being passed in `JSON.parse` is undefined. I tried to use `console.log(typeof(data))` to check if it really is undefined, but it outputs 2 things. First it outputs string, then outputs undefined. Afterwards, it displays the error, but the chart gets displayed successfully. Here's my code:

```
function aggregator(field, size) {
    /*Build jSON query string*/
    var jString = '{"aggs": { "group_by_date": { "terms": { "field": "' + field + '", "size" : ' + size + '} } } }';

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);   /*Load Chart*/

    /*Sending and retrieving data using Ajax*/
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
            qSet: jString,
            size: size
        },
        success: drawChart
    });
}

var drawChart = function(data)
{   
    console.log(typeof(data));
    data = JSON.parse(data);  /*Convert the data back into an array*/

    var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();  /*Set up the chart*/

    chartData.addColumn('string', 'year'); 
    chartData.addColumn('number', 'Records');

    /*For loop to add rows*/
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        chartData.addRow(data[i]);
    }

    var options = {
        title: 'Arrival Data'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chartContainer'));
    chart.draw(chartData, options);
};
```

What is the reason for this error? Why do I receive 2 outputs (string and then undefined) when I do console.log(typeof(data))? How can I fix it?

Comment: you should use JSON.stringify(yourjsonstring) method to create Json and send this to server. Now you are sending just string.

Comment: @guest271314 — The question tells you that: "First it outputs string, then outputs undefined"

Comment: @NumanKIZILIRMAK — What makes you think the server is expecting the data to be JSON encoded instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: `datatype` should be `dataType`

Comment: @Quentin  datatype: 'json' is made me thought

Comment: @NumanKIZILIRMAK — `dataType` describes the expected **response**. Don't confuse it with `contentType` (which describes the request).

Comment: @Quentin Not sure how `console.log(typeof data)` at `$.ajax()` response could log `undefined`?

Comment: @Quentin yes you are right, sorry about confusion

Comment: @guest271314 — It doesn't. That's what you get when the function is called by `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback`

Comment: @Quentin _"First it outputs string, then outputs undefined."_ Then what is `data` at `$.ajax()` `success` callback?

Comment: @guest271314 — a string

Comment: @Quentin Yes, a string consisting of what?

Comment: @guest271314 — the JSON response from the server

Comment: @Quentin The why `JSON.parse()` error?

Comment: @guest271314 — Because that's what you get when you call `JSON.parse(undefined)` (i.e. the *other* time the function is called).

Comment: @guest271314 —  *First it outputs string* — which is JSON and it parses just fine — *then outputs undefined* — which is not JSON and throws a parse error.

Comment: @Quentin You mentioned `data` at `$.ajax()` is a string at previous comment, not `undefined`, unless you mean the string `"undefined"`? You appear to have the expected progression correct at your Answer.

Comment: @guest271314 — "You mentioned data at $.ajax() is a string at previous comment, not undefined" — Read my previous comments. Read my answer. The function is being called twice. The value passed to the first argument is different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I receive 2 outputs (string and then undefined) when I do console.log(typeof(data))?

Because you are calling the function twice.

1. `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`
2. `success: drawChart`

Only call it when you get the data.

---

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` lets you specify a function to run when the API is available.

Create a new function which makes your Ajax request and call that when the API has loaded.

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(sendAjaxRequest); /*Load Chart*/

function sendAjaxRequest() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
      qSet: jString,
      size: size
    },
    success: drawChart
  });
}
```